# How can I populate one dataset from other two datasets? SAS

Tags: sql, sas, dataset, proc-sql

I have a dataset final with variable A B C D E of which A,B,C are numeric and D,E are character.I want to delete the data from dataset final and populate it with new data from dataset One and dataset Two.

Dataset One has variables A B C and dataset Two has D and E.

Example:

FINAL

```
 A B C D E
 1 2 3 a b
 4 5 6 c d
```

I want to delete the old content.Then IT should look like

FINAL

```
     A B C D E
```

I have data set One and Two as

One

```
    A B C
    0 2 4
    1 2 3
    7 6 4
```

Two

```
    D E
    x y
    p q
```

I want to update FINAL with One and Two content like

FINAL

```
    A B C D E
    0 2 4 x y
    1 2 3 p q
    7 6 4
```

Comment: It does not make any sense to delete the old data and insert new records. Just make a new dataset that has the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `merge` (documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1i8w2bwu1fn5kn1gpxj18xttbb0.htm)):

```
data final;
   merge one two;
run;
```

This is a bit more painful using `proc sql`.

Comment: There is no comma in the MERGE statement.